Преобразование и копирование в буффер обмена webp/canvas -> png картинки
Хочу написать плагин хрома для Wildberries, который позволит брать картинку товара в буффер обмена.
Проблема в том, что там есть только Webp и canvas изображения.
Чтобы скопировать webp/canvas их нужно преобразовать в blob тип, чего политика CORS хрома не дает сделать
Использую следующую функцию:
canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob})]));

Политика ругаетя на метод .toBlob() либо .toDataURL()
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Есть ли какой-нибудь обходной путь, чтобы скопировать ее в буффер в формате png/jpg или это программно невозможно?
P.S. Делаю для себя, а не в публичный доступ. Возможно подшаманить с настройками самого браузера

Прошу прощения, но то что вы нагородили — "кто в лес, кто по дрова". Если вам нужен краткий и не имеющий никакого прикладного смысла ответ, то... для того чтобы получить blob вам достаточно получить картинку по url при помощи fetch и её результат в response.blob(). Но может попробуете объяснить конечную цель вашего расширения более понятным языком. В частности зачем вам эта картинка вообще понадобилась в клипборде?

я указал, что картинку мне нужно брать с карточки товара wildberries. По url картинку можно получить только в webp формате, но чтобы ее скопировать в буффер нужно сначала преобразовать с помощью .toBlob(), чего CORS не дает сделать. А canvas формат тоже нужно преобразовать в blob  с помощью .toDataURL(), который использовать невозможно из-за того же CORS.
От того и становится вопрос, возможно ли осуществить эту задач впринципе.
В борд хочу копировать для упрощения рутины, чтобы не приходилось скачивать

Создайте БД или отдельный сервер отправляйте картинку туда а потом со своего сервара или БД делайте с ней все что хотите или как вариант позвоните к Wildberries и сделайте официальную интеграцию с ними

мне не нужна интеграция с вб, т.к. это решение не для публичного пользования. на сервер CORS не даст отправить ничего

Я прекрасно умею читать. Зачем вы повторяете ту же бессмыслицу, что и в посте? Объясните что вы собираетесь сделать потом с этой картинкой, а не вот этот набор букв. Я вам уже сказал, что blob получить проще простого. И, чтобы вам совсем уж было понятно, то все эти ваши CORS для расширения браузера вообще фиолетовы, если знать что делаешь. Вам нужна помощь? Так потрудитесь описать задачу, а не то что вы нагромоздили.

Как еще более точно можно описать то, что мне нужно? Мне нужно чтобы картинка попала в буффер. Разве имеет смысл то, каким образом я буду использовать ее дальше? CORS тут очень даже причем, ибо методы, что я указал выше невозможно использовать на домене WB и, соответственно нет возможности преобразовать картинки в blob. В том числе нет возможности получить ее по URL. Соответветственно, ваше предложение не актуально

Ну, раз вы по третьему разу решили повторить полную бессмыслицу... Повторюсь и я: ? 1. браузерным расширениям пофигу на CORS, если знать! что делаешь  2. нет ничего проще чем получить тот или иной участок на странице в виде blob. Не вижу смысла в продолжении диалога и какой-либо помощи, вы ведь уже всё знаете лучше.

Если браузерным расширениям на это пофигу - попробуйте загрузить сторонний скрипт с помощью расширения через http =) Если blob получить так просто, вы можете предложить работающий способ в моем случае, ибо то что я видел выше уж никак не подходит. Если у вас нет такого решения, то пожалуй да, нам нет смысла продолжать диалог

вы пропустили видимо мимо глаз и уперлись в то что вам не понравилось, то есть вы взяли и обрезали мое предложение до того что вам нужна интеграция а про БД вы видимо не поняли отправляете в БД свою картинку которую получаете GET запросом в формате webp а уже из своего БД достаете то что вам нужно в блоб без каких либо корсов, как вариант можно попробовать загрузить расширение в режиме с ослабления CORS погуглите если интересно что это
